# Constant in viewDidLoad error

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to make a simple addition program, but when I put my let function in the viewDidLoad, it gives me this error:

> initialization of immutable value 'doMath' was never used; consider
>   replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it.

Here is the code

```
let doMath: (Int!, Int!) -> Int =
mathFunction(text1, text2)
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something new in swift2 that is if you are not using the particular variable then replace it with `_` or use that variable, that's why it suggests you to replace your variable name with `_`. This is mainly designed for reducing memory and CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error. It is a warning.

> initialization of immutable value 'doMath' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing

What this means is that you never use `doMath` after declaring it. As soon as you actually use `doMath` in your code, the warning will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as stated it is a warning letting you know that you have declared a variable that has not been used either before or after the declaration.  The warning message suggests that you replace the variable (doMath) with a simple (_) as doMath is not used outside of the declaration.

Your options are to ignore the warning message, or to use it outside of the declaration.

You could also set up the function completely different if you are only looking for a simple addition function.

```
var firstNumber = 4
var secondNumber = 6
var doMath = (firstNumber + secondNumber)
print(doMath)
```